# How to reload data in a Fuel UX repeater

Tags: javascript, fuelux

I am using the newly released [Fuel UX 3.1](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/javascript.html#repeater) in a web application. I managed to set up a Repeater widget with data coming from the backend, however I can only render it once.

```js
$('#myRepeater').repeater({
    dataSource: dataSource
});
```

So this block of code renders the repeater, however I cannot change the dataSource after this and render it again with the new values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try calling

```
$('#myRepeater').repeater('render')
```

to reload dataSource; works for me.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that :) By the way I had to drop fuelux in the meantime because of this bug: https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues/774 .

Answer (score 0):

Well, it does not really answer my original question, however this solves my problem. When I want to reload the Repeater with other data, I actually create a new one, with another `dataSource`.

So new my Ajax request to the server looks like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...some url...',
    type: 'post',
    data: JSON.stringify(payload),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        var dataSource = new MyDataSource(data, columns);
        // the repeater already exists
        if ($('#myRepeater .repeater-canvas').contents().length !== 0) {
            var enclosingDiv = $('#myRepeater').parent();
            var markup = $('#myRepeater').repeater('destroy');
            enclosingDiv.html(markup);
        }
        // creating the repeater normally
        $('#myRepeater').repeater({
            dataSource: dataSource
        });
    }
});
```

If someone is curious about `MyDataSource`, it is actually a simple function, which allows me to put my data into the `dataSource` function, expected by the Fuel UX repeater:

```
var MyDataSource = new function (data, columns) {
    return function (options, callback) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing a similar problem with fuleUx dataGrid where i am trying to create dynamic columns with dynamic data, could you please elaborate your var MyDataSource = new function()...  I have posted a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370391/fuelux-change-dynamic-datasource-columns